# looping thru a list of checkboxes and saving the values, not working properly

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm having a bit of a problem with this code.

The program gives me a list of checkboxes but a user ID. then u user can change his selection and push the save button (id="btnSaveUserIntersts") and i am trying to save in the hidden textbox all the values of the checkboxes that was choosen.

The problem is that i am getting all the time the same selections that came form the database and not getting the new selection that the user made.

Can any one tell me what am i doing wrong here?

```
$(document).ready(
function()
{ 
    $('#btnSaveUserIntersts').bind(
        'click',
        function()
        {
            var strCheckBoxChecked = new String();
            $('input[type=checkbox][checked]').each(
                function()
                {
                    strCheckBoxChecked += $(this).val();
                    strCheckBoxChecked += ',';
                }
            );
            $('#hidUserInterests').val(strCheckBoxChecked);
        }
    );
}
```

);

10x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```
    $('input:checkbox:checked').each(
        function()
        {
            strCheckBoxChecked += $(this).val();
            strCheckBoxChecked += ',';
        }
    );
```

As the selector instead of what you're currently using.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/), it's far prettier:

```
var strCheckBoxChecked = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function()
    return this.value;
}).get().join(",");
```

And the selector you are using is *close*, `$('input[type=checkbox][checked=checked]')`